# $location.path() giving full URL instead of relative path in Meteor Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to show a banner div when the route is not `/hideBanner`. This is a webpage made using Angular with Meteor using the [`angular-with-blaze`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/angular-with-blaze) and `angularui:angular-ui-router` packages.

**Problem:** However `$location.path()` is giving me `http://localhost:3000/hideBanner` instead of `/hideBanner`.

Why is it giving the full URL?

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('BannerCtrl', function($scope, $location) {

    $scope.showBanner = function() {
        console.log($location.path());
        return $location.path() != '/hideBanner';
    }

})
```

**HTML of `index.ng.html`**

```
<div class="banner" ng-controller='BannerCtrl' ng-show='showBanner'></div>
```

Comment: That's weird, what kind of routing do you use?

Comment: @Michelem I'm using the regular `ui.router`

Comment: mmm could you move the `console.log($location.path());` outside the `showBanner` function just to try if it returns the correct one? (I don't think) Then this `ng-show='showBanner'` should be `ng-show='showBanner()'`

Comment: @Michelem Yes changing to `ng-show='showBanner()` caused it to work now :)